# How do I transfer a table from localhost to remote MySQL server?

Tags: mysql

I've done some research but not finding a satisfactory solution to my problem. I need to transfer two tables from my localhost database to a remote database with help of `mysqldump`. This is the code I'm using but it just prints out some generic text about the MySQL executable.

```
mysqldump --opt --host="localhost" --password="PASSWORD_LOCALHOST" db_name table1 table2 | mysql --host="remote_host" --password="PASSWORD_REMOTE" -C db_name table1 table2
```

What is the corrext syntax to successfully transfer the tables?

Comment: Can't you use phpMyAdmin?

Comment: mysql client doesn't take table parameter, remove "table1 table2" from the end of command.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I need to have this as part of a script procedure. Doing it via PHPMyAdmin or with a GUI application is a no-brainer.

Comment: Also you specify a password, but don't specify username

Answer (score -1):

Do it this way:

- Export your database from localhost
- Go to the cPanel from your website (www.yoursite.com/cpanel) and login there
- Create a database
- Go to phpMyAdmin in the cPanel
- Import the database that you exported from the localhost
- You have the database imported
- Now you can play with MySQL in the cPanel